# How to get data from dynamic web elements[id] and write that data in excel dynamically in the adjacent cell of the input data

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, apache-poi

[image]Actually, I am automating a web chatbot. I am facing a problem to get the data from dynamic elements which have the same class name for all the web elements related to chat text. see below for the HTML code.

```html
 <div class="box-body" style="flex: 1;overflow: hidden"><!-- Conversations are loaded here--><div class="direct-chat-messages"><!-- Message. Default to the left--><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="35e2e858-dece-eb9e-70b2-ced0d28849e3"><div class="direct-chat-msg right"><div class="direct-chat-text">hi</div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="09ccac6a-00a0-493f-a489-621af631c5df"><div class="direct-chat-msg left"><div class="direct-chat-text"><span>Hello Kamala@96! I am Maya, your personal assistant. How may I help you?</span><div class="actionButton container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Book a cab')">Book a cab</div><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Book a movie')">Book a movie</div><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Recharge')">Recharge</div><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Book Bus')">Book Bus</div><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Play games')">Play games</div><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('News')">News</div></div></div></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="8808fb8f-5358-b71f-2240-a1480daa12ef"><div class="direct-chat-msg right"><div class="direct-chat-text">book a cab</div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="5678e7f3-0c76-40b6-ad56-c2e8113f6657"><div class="direct-chat-msg left"><div class="direct-chat-text"><span></span></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="2141f74e-9250-4ea5-8876-ea0760839ae2"><div class="direct-chat-msg left"><div class="direct-chat-text"><span>Welcome ! Let me get you a cab. You can type <b>cancel</b> at any point to exit this conversation</span></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="0e18992e-a084-4bcd-9407-0ce1c1cddede"><div class="direct-chat-msg left"><div class="direct-chat-text"><span>Your pickup location is: C1.04.08, Tower A, 4th Floor, Rattha Tek Meadows, Elcot Sez, Sholinganallur, Chennai   </span><div class="actionButton container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Change Source')">Change Source</div></div></div></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="b374870c-f988-4365-a279-1f83c115e21f"><div class="direct-chat-msg left"><div class="direct-chat-text"><span>You can change your cab preference from here.</span><div class="actionButton container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Ola')">Ola</div><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Cheapest Cab')">Cheapest Cab</div></div></div></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="ad18d10f-21d9-40de-83c4-686cbcd16ada"><div class="direct-chat-msg left bus-cards-container"><div id="options" class="container-fluid"></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="f0f350c4-46d7-fc8f-e48b-943f23a8ec76"><div class="direct-chat-msg right"><div class="direct-chat-text">ola</div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="659efca6-e2d5-4e4a-a7aa-9f6e056deb7c"><div class="direct-chat-msg left bus-cards-container"><div id="options" class="container-fluid"></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="eac2c45a-33ea-45be-824b-9dfa2b79c29d"><div class="direct-chat-msg left"><div class="direct-chat-text"><span>Or you can change your cab preference from here.</span><div class="actionButton container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Uber')">Uber</div><div class="options-div" onclick="triggerAnswerNikki('Cheapest Cab')">Cheapest Cab</div></div></div></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="2b5b902b-4e1c-0e3c-c94d-5fd7bf0f7c6e"><div class="direct-chat-msg right"><div class="direct-chat-text">Uber</div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="51ee1640-95bf-4d20-987e-5800061e798d"><div class="direct-chat-msg left bus-cards-container"><div id="options" class="container-fluid"></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:36 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="440f92b7-0680-c379-1345-96b6ada25ba4"><div class="direct-chat-msg right"><div class="direct-chat-text">cancel</div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06:37 pm</span></div></div><div class="chat-individuals clearfix" id="9be75061-3c4b-4627-b37c-a7447719bf64"><div class="direct-chat-msg left"><div class="direct-chat-text"><span>We'll meet again! </span></div></div><div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"><span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">06:37 pm</span></div></div></div></div>
```

both these classes are the same for all the text in the conversation. and the id is also kept on changing since it is a dynamic web element.
please help me handling the response of chatbot by writing it to the excel in the same cell of excel.[image]

Comment: Can you share the URL of that chat client? In general, what I'm thinking is locate the class 'chat-individuals', go up one div and start a listener that watches if more 'chat-individuals' have appeared and takes the innerHTML from each new class. But the URL would be most helpful here.

Comment: @Alichino even if I share URL is not enough for you. you have to get authorization by login id and password which is confidential. I can share you the entire HTML source code of a conversation between a user and chatbot. or please provide me your email id, I can try to send new temporary login id and pwd for you.

Comment: Let's try with the HTML, I'll see if I can do something with it.

Comment: yeah, I have edited the body with updated HTML code, please have a look and let me know how to solve this problem

Comment: Hmm it's not easy... I'll try to think of something, after work maybe :)

Comment: ok please try.@Alichino

Comment: or you can also give me a logic for printing the response from bot into the excel(in the adjacent cell of that input in excel) after the complete conversation(not dynamically).